# Can I highlight a selected list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using jQuery for a list item click event, is it possible to highlight the selected item somehow?

```
$('#listReports').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
  var filename = $(this).text();
  // Any highlight methods or css tricks that I can add/remove for each click
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods:

```
.selected {
   property: value
}
```

```
$('#listReports').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
     //var filename = $(this).text();
     $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: probably best if the statement to remove the selected class is a bit more specific as the class might be used elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#listReports').delegate('li', 'click', function () {

     var filename = $(this).text();
     $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
     $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});


.highlight{
  background-color: #ddd;  /*or whatever color */
  }
```

Comment: This won't handle a situation where a li has already been selected.

Comment: fixed, I try to get answer posted too fast some times

Comment: I hear ya, i got half way through mine before 3 answers were posted

Comment: @undefined gets me everytime

Answer (score 0):

Probably best for you to use the .on() method as the jQuery website states

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

Try instead

```
$("#listReports").on( "click", "li", function( ) {
    var filename = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")
}
```

Obviously then style the `.selected` class appropriately